# Battery supply vs laptop supply

Tags: arduino-nano

**Setup:**
I have wired up the arduino, motor and battery as shown.
[image]
(12 and 5 of L293D are not connected to anything)
D11,D10...D6 means that those pins on the L293D are connected to digital pins 11-6 on the nano.

**Problem:**
The motors spin for a while but then they slow down to a stop. If I unplug the battery, wait for 5 mins or so and then reattach the battery then the motors start spinning but after a while they stop again. Now if I keep the setup the same except I unplug the battery and connect the arduino to my laptop then the laptop manages to power not only my arduino but also my motors (although they spin a little bit less faster than with the battery). And when I do it with the laptop the motors don't stop spinning.
Because of this I thought my battery might be faulty so I attached a fresh 9V energiser battery. Then the same thing happens. The motors spin for a while then stop and after I plug in the battery after a while they spin again.
I tried this yet again with a fresh battery and the same thing happened.

**Question**
What could be causing this?
Why are all of my batteries incapable of powering the motor steadily and why is my laptop capable of doing this?

CODE:
(all this does is make both motors spin)
[image]

Comment: Please no code as image. You can copy and paste the code as text into the question and format it as code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button or pressing control+K

Comment: your battery does not last very long ... what does that tell you about the battery?

Comment: Does it tell me that the battery does not have enough current? I tried to test this out and I used a series of AA batteries which (although there were 6 of them) output only 7V due to their usage in the past. These batteries made my motor spin faster and for way longer than my 9V duracell battery.  So i think it might be because of current.

Comment: @Sanchez2009 that is correct ... the 9 V battery contains six AAAA cells, same as when you created a 9 V battery from six AA cells, but with very small capacity to provide current ... try using larger cells, like size C or D